# Google charts don't display lines in LineChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, google-visualization, ember-data

I'm using Google Chart with EmberJS 2. I don't use component cause don't support promises I needed, so I created a service. And I'm using two charts on the same callback. Follow a fiddle to show code work and a print when don't work in my application.

```js
var reviews = [{
 "creation": { "created": 1421881568000 },
 "statistics": { "rating": 2 }
},
{
 "creation": { "created": 1415449027000 },
 "statistics": { "rating": 5 }
},
{
 "creation": { "created": 1381797902000 },
 "statistics": { "rating": 1 }
},
{
 "creation": { "created": 1378908249000 },
 "statistics": { "rating": 5 }
},
{
 "creation": { "created": 1376907381000 },
 "statistics": { "rating": 4 }
},
{
 "creation": { "created": 1372939458000 },
 "statistics": { "rating": 4 }
},
{
 "creation": { "created": 1350954490000 },
 "statistics": { "rating": 5 }
},
{
 "creation": { "created": 1350954289000 },
 "statistics": { "rating": 1 }
},
{
 "creation": { "created": 1322225085000 },
 "statistics": { "rating": 5 }
}];

google.charts.load('43', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
 var ratingByDate, dataToPie, dataToLine, options, lineChart, pieChart;
 dataToPie = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataToPie.addColumn('string', 'Avali\ç\ões');
 dataToPie.addColumn('number', 'Total');
 dataToPie.addRows([
  ["1 estrela", 1],
  ["2 estrelas", 2],
  ["3 estrelas", 1],
  ["4 estrelas", 2],
  ["5 estrelas", 4]
 ]);

 pieChart = new google.visualization.PieChart($('.pie-chart')[0]);
    pieChart.draw(dataToPie, {
        title: 'Porcentagem das 50 avalia\ç\ões',
        pieHole: 0.3,
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
        colors: ['#BBBBBD', '#F00745', '#C00337', '#5A4237', '#EE0B56'],
        tooltip: { isHtml: true},
    });

    ratingByDate = reviews.map(review => [
        new Date(review.creation.created),
        +review.statistics.rating
    ]);

 dataToLine = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 dataToLine.addColumn('date', 'Data');
 dataToLine.addColumn('number', 'Avaliações');
 dataToLine.addRows(ratingByDate);

 lineChart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('#lineChart')[0]);
 lineChart.draw(dataToLine, {
  title: 'Avaliações',
  legend: { position: 'bottom' },
  curveType: 'function',
  pointSize: 3,
  pointsVisible: true,
  crosshair: { trigger: 'both' }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pie-chart"></div>
<div id="lineChart"></div>
```

The [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4vtpjac/) is much close which I do in my application.

Follow a image which reproduce the problem [image]

Comment: I don't see any issue in the output. Is this something browser-specific? It could also be related to the recent release breaking things because of caching. Your example here is fixed to version 43, so it might not be affected. If you were loading with 'current' instead it could be affected by the release problem.

Comment: @nbering I don't think so. I run on Google Chrome.

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Comment: Yes, I still. For my application work I change for a Material view and worked.